# Using SQL to create Ratios for paint

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to create a query where a user can modify an amount of paint in a recipe, that will in turn create a ratio for that paint in the recipe and I'm having a hard time setting the ratio. I tried to create this in sql fiddle but cannot apparently get the schema correct, or it is simply down currently as I keep getting errors and cannot figure out what the sql fiddle isn't building the schema. This is currently what I have:

[image: example1]

and this is the query I've created thus far to get to this point:

```
select 
RID,
PBC,
RawP,
Amt,
(select SUM(Amt) from Pratio as C where c.RID = d.RID) as [Amountsum]
from Pratio as D
group by RID,PBC,RawP,Amt
```

I've tried this to add in the ratio amounts but it fails:

```
select 
RID,
PBC,
RawP,
Amt,
(select SUM(Amt) from Pratio as C where c.RID = d.RID) as [Amountsum],
(select 
SUM(f.Amt) as [Amountsum],
sum(e.amt/f.amt)
 from Pratio as e 
 inner join Pratio as f 
  e.RID=f.RID) as [testing]
from Pratio as D
group by RID,PBC,RawP,Amt
```

Ideally the ratio column would take for example on the first line, the value of "Amt" and divide it by the value in "Amountsum".

Any help would be much appreciated and here is the sqlfiddle attempt I have if someone sees what I did wrong, trying to help as much as I can! Thanks all!

[SQL Fiddle Attempt](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18)

Here would be to create a sample table with the values I have:

```
Create table Pratio 
(indx INT,                     
 RID int,                     
 PBC nvarchar(MAX),                     
 RawP int,                     
 Amt float)
 insert into Pratio 
(indx,RID,PBC,RawP,Amt)
Values 
(1,255,'P',27,8),
(2,255,'P',29,3),
(3,255,'P',22,1.5),
(4,293,'B',22,8),
(5,293,'B',44,3)
;
```

Comment: Pictures of sample data don't really help. We can't do anything with it. Post your sample data as DDL (`CREATE`) and DML (`INSERT`) statements. Also, what are you expecting as the output here? *(The SQL Fiddle you've linked to is also completely blank)*

Comment: Your SQL Fiddle attempt link doesn't work for me

Comment: Yea I'm sorry, I added at the bottom of my question what I'm attempting to put into sql fiddle as I'm still rather new to it, and I usually don't create tables by statement I just right click/add etc.

Ideally I want it to take the "AMT" amount for the column, and divide that amount by the "Amountsum" column to establish the ratio of that specific paint to the recipe

Comment: You can create it any way you want and then choose to script it out from the table in SSMS - right click is your friend here  Script as..

Comment: When you say "fails" do you mean you get an error (then post the message) or that it doesn't do what you want (then post your desired results)?

Comment: @DaveHolt, could you please provide your expected output

Comment: Be careful using float here. If you need accurate values you should use numeric or decimal instead since float is an approximate datatype.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're wanting the AmountSum to be based on all rows with the same RID.  Then do the math of Amt divided by the AmountSum.

You can simplify SUM and partition it by that RID column.  Give this a try:

```
DECLARE @Pratio TABLE
    (
        [indx] INT
      , [RID] INT
      , [PBC] NVARCHAR(MAX)
      , [RawP] INT
      , [Amt] FLOAT
    );


INSERT INTO @Pratio (
                        [indx]
                      , [RID]
                      , [PBC]
                      , [RawP]
                      , [Amt]
                    )
VALUES ( 1, 255, 'P', 27, 8 )
     , ( 2, 255, 'P', 29, 3 )
     , ( 3, 255, 'P', 22, 1.5 )
     , ( 4, 293, 'B', 22, 8 )
     , ( 5, 293, 'B', 44, 3 );

SELECT *
     , SUM([Amt]) OVER ( PARTITION BY [RID] ) AS [AmountSumByRID]
     , [Amt] / SUM([Amt]) OVER ( PARTITION BY [RID] ) AS [Ratio]
FROM   @Pratio;
```

Comment: This is what I would have done (including changing the DDL to a variable!) I would also change amount to decimal though. I hate FLOAT.

Comment: Thank you so much! This solved it, I appreciate the help greatly, greatly my friend! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

You can try below using subquery

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=d26f9f936b2ae92392e9567d8169624a)

```
select RID,PBC,RawP,Amt,amountsum,cast(amt/amountsum as numeric(5,2)) as ratio from
(select RID,PBC,RawP,Amt,
(select SUM(Amt) from Pratio as C where c.RID = d.RID) as [Amountsum]
from Pratio as D
group by RID,PBC,RawP,Amt)a
```

Comment: I appreciate the answer, this also works, Thank you very much for your help! I appreciate it greatly!